# bidimensional random variable raised to a power vs multiply by itself

Tags: self-study, distributions

This is a student question, so please be kind.
  Let's say that I have a bidimensional random variable X. If I multiply X by itself( i.e. X*X*...X n times) there will be an resultant bidimensional variable, say Y. On the other hand if I do X^n power then the resultant bidimensional variabile will be something different from Y. Why is that so ?
     Thank you in advance !

Comment: Probably because you can't multiple X by itself a negative amount of times, while doing X to the power of a negative n is possible.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Also, I don't quite follow your situation, can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't teven know what you are talking about. Can you give an example of a "bidimensional" random variable?  Doesn't that mean two-dimensional? If so, what does $X X$ mean if $X$ is bidimesnional?  Give a specific example of the two different ways of calculating something and show us the difference.

Comment: If we have a bidimensional variable :  with x1 = 1 , x2 = 2 ( the values of the variable )  and p1 = 1/2 and p2 = 1/2 ( the probabilities associated with the values) then if I multiply X by itself I obtain a distribution with the values : x1' = 1  < --- > p1' = 1/4 ; x2' = 2 <----> p2' = 1/2; x3' = 4 <---> p3' = 1/4 . On the other hand if I rise the variable to 2nd power then I obtain x1'' = 1 < --- > p1'' = 1/2 and x2'' = 2 <---> p2'' = 1/ 2. Yes, it means two-dimensional...this is the terminology used in university

Comment: You seem to be horribly confusing things. I suggest editing your question and writing everything out very clearly.  If $A$ and $B$ are each one-dimensional random variables having the same distribution and which are independent (i.e., i.i.d.), $A B$ will have a different distribution than $A^2$.  I think this gets to the heart of at least part of your confusion.

Comment: Ok, but why AB will have a different distribution than A^2 ? Please give me a reference to study or a hint. I don't quite get the concept...

Comment: $A$ and $B$ were assumed to be independent.  $A$ and $A$ are not independent.  That is the key.